# Graphite summarize returning inconsistent data

Tags: graphite, statsd, graphite-carbon

I've set up a two-node Graphite cluster connected using `carbon-relay`:

[image: Graphite cluster]

I sent 500 counters for my metric `cluster-test-500` over ~1min period, at approximately 60/10 seconds.

Based on my aggregation rules:

```
Meta data:
  aggregation method: sum
  max retention: 31536000
  xFilesFactor: 0

Archive 0 info:
  offset: 52
  seconds per point: 10
  points: 2160
  retention: 21600
  size: 25920

Archive 1 info:
  offset: 25972
  seconds per point: 60
  points: 10080
  retention: 604800
  size: 120960

Archive 2 info:
  offset: 146932
  seconds per point: 600
  points: 52560
  retention: 31536000
  size: 630720
```

The data appeared in both nodes' Whisper DBs:

```
data:
12
63
61
62
63
60
61
57
0

data:
261
239
0

data:
500
0
```

Then, when I queried Graphite using the `summarize` function, over the past day:

```
http://graphite.mysite.com/render?target=summarize(stats.counters.cluster-test-500.*.*.*.count,"1day","sum","False")&format=json&tz=UTC&from=18:00_20130923&until=18:00_20130924
```

It returns inconsistent results by simply re-running the same query:

```
[{"target": "summarize(stats.counters.cluster-test-500.count, \"1day\", \"sum\", true)", "datapoints": [[302.0, 1379959260]]}]
[{"target": "summarize(stats.counters.cluster-test-500.count, \"1day\", \"sum\", true)", "datapoints": [[500.0, 1379959260]]}]
[{"target": "summarize(stats.counters.cluster-test-500.count, \"1day\", \"sum\", true)", "datapoints": [[261.0, 1379959260]]}]
[{"target": "summarize(stats.counters.cluster-test-500.count, \"1day\", \"sum\", true)", "datapoints": [[63.0, 1379959260]]}]
```

Which appears to result from seemingly random summations of time segments in the WhisperDB file. What on earth could be causing this?